# AngularJS http return value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to write a function in AngularJS that returns a value (actually it is a string). That value is returned by a http request, but async is driving me crazy.

My first attempt was:

```
this.readParameter = function(key) {
  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "XXXXXXX",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    return response.data;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    throw new Error("Error");
  })
};
```

But of course it does not work because of Angular async features (response.data is undefined)

What is the way to do it? I just want to return the value (string), so I can use this function like

```
var a = readParameter("key1")
```

Comment: There is no other way than to return the `$http` promise and use `then()` with `readParameter()` to get the data you received asynchronously.

Comment: But is it possible to wrap it into a function so I can use it directly like var a = readParameter("myKey")? Or must I forget it? Thank you

Comment: No. Don't treat asnychronous as if it is synchronous, you might need some refresher on **[what asynchronous and synchronous is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean)**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you can do is define some variable with initial value outside function and on response set value inside success function instead of returning it.

[Delegator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_(programming)) pattern works great here to assign `$http` task to some service and use callback method for response.

`Controller` (Call Service for specific request) -> `Service` (Manage request params and other things and return factory response to Controller) -> `Factory` (Send request and return it to Service)

Basic example of Callback

```
var myVariable = '';
function myFunction (key, callback) {
  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "XXXXXXX",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      callback(response);
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    throw new Error("Error");
  })
};

function myCallbackFunction(response) {
   myVariable = response.data; // assign value to variable
   // Do some work after getting response
}

myFunction('MY_KEY', myCallbackFunction);
```

This is basic example to set value but instead use callback pattern from above example.

```
var myvariable = '';
function myFunction (key) {
  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "XXXXXXX",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      myvariable = response.data; // set data to myvariable
      // Do something else on success response
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    throw new Error("Error");
  })
};
myFunction('MY_KEY');
```

Comment: I have tested it and response.date is still undefined in that way. I will study delegator pattern anyway, maybe the solution is there. Thank you

Comment: Use `response.data`, not `response.date` if by mistake you have written than ignore it. If problem doesn't solve then make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and add link at here.

Comment: It works. I was not understanding well the callback, but you are right.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to mix async and sync programming. Instead use a callback to use like

```
readParameter("key1", callback)
```

for example:

```
    this.readParameter = function(key, callback) {
  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "XXXXXXX",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    callback(response)
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    throw new Error("Error");
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this by using promise:

Example :

in Service (invoicesAPIservice => invoicesapiservice.js) you use:

```
angular.module('app')
.service('invoicesAPIservice', function ($http) {
     this.connectToAPI= function () {

     return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            var options = {
                method:'GET',
                url :'',
                headers:{
                    'X-User-Agent': '....',
                    'Authorization': '....',
                }
            };

           $http(options).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    resolve(response);
                //console.log(response);
            },function errorCallback(response) {
                reject(response);
            })
     });
});
```

});

and in your Controller (mainCtrl=> mainCtrl.js):

```
angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope,invoicesAPIservice) {
  $scope.connectToAPI=function () {           
      invoicesAPIservice.connectToAPI().then(function (content) {
           console.log(content.statusText);
      }.catch(function (err) {
        //console.log(err);
        alert("Server is Out");
    });
 }
```

});

And in your page : index.html:

```
<button ng-click="connectToAPI()"></button>
```

:)